# Trabajar con Modelos en Django

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes: en primer lugar, gracias a los que se tomen el tiempo en contestarme, os dejo la siguiente consulta:

Tengo un modelo en django del siguiente estilo:

```
class miModelo(models.Model):

    Nombre     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parametro1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    parametro2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    #
    #
    parametron = models.IntegerField(null=True)'''
```

Este modelo recibe información de la siguiente manera: Tengo 5 nombres diferentes con sus respectivos parámetros, y consigo obtener el resultado que quiero, cada entrada registra el nombre y sus parámetros. Y no hay limite de entradas, es decir puedo tener n entradas repitiendo los nombres pero con diferentes parámetros para cada entrada. El problema viene ahora:

Quiero leer la información de la base de datos que genera para alimentar a otros 2 modelos:

El primer modelo tiene que hacer lo siguiente: En lugar de tener n entradas quiero que agrupe las entradas de la primera tabla por nombre para obtener una tabla con 5 nombres y que sume los parámetros que vayan entrando en la tabla principal, obteniendo el total de cada parametro para los 5 nombres.

El segundo modelo hace algo parecido: quiero obtener la misma tabla con 5 nombres pero ahora que me de la media de los parámetros.

Se me ocurre que una vez alimento la tabla principal, crear las 2 tablas que quiero, y una vez actualice la tabla principal, borrar y volver a crear cada tabla con annotate(sum(parametro)) y con annotate(Avg(parametro)). No sé si esta manera es la única que hay o hay una manera más eficiente que sólo actualice los campos de los parámetros en lugar de tener que eliminar y crear la tabla cada vez.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!